# Can sunspot / solar boost results that are in a certain group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I have three models (in rails) associated as follows

```
class Content
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Group
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end
```

When I do a search for content in Sunspot, I would like all content to appear. However I would like content that is in any group that the current user is a member of to appear first.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it you should be able as adding an extra column to the Solr document, and sorting on that column.

Comment: If you could show some sample code on how to do this that would be awesome - thanks